# Error al realizar petición post con entity framework

Tags: c#, api, entity-framework

Mi consulta es la siguiente:
[image: Es petición post donde los campos con oAutorizacion es la información a introducir en BD]

donde voy a actualizar evaluando que el parámetro ot coincida con uno que ya este insertado previamente, pero al enviarlo me marca errores y no se como solucionarlo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**El error lo obtienes por lo siguiente:**

1. Creas un objeto `AutorizacionCLS`, pero como recién lo estas creando, este es un objeto nulo.
2. Al entrar a la validación del `if(oAutorizacionCLS.Ot.Contains(ot))`, estas validando de la siguiente manera: Si `oAutorizacionCLS.Ot` contiene `ot` entonces pasas a procesar lo que esta dentro del `if`.
3. ¿Pero qué pasa con esta validación? Resulta que tu objeto `oAutorizacionCLS.Ot` es nulo, porque lo creaste pero nunca le asignaste valores. Entonces eh aquí el error `object reference not set to an instance of an object`.

Si quieres validar que `ot` este dentro de tu objeto `oAutorizacionCLS.Ot`, asegúrate de consultar primero los datos que necesitas actualizar y así llenar tu objeto con datos en los que podrás validar si `ot` esta dentro de tu objeto con valores.

Comment: El el pto 1 deberias aclarar bien que el objeto nulo es ot y no AutorizacionCLS

Comment: Entonces es mas recomendable que haga una búsqueda antes de que haga la inserción eso es lo que seria mucho mejor? y Japv creo que si ya entendi leyendo mas el error